# How to configure remove JVM for JUnit in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

How we can run test case of JUnit on remote JVM in Eclipse.

My server is running outside of Eclipse. Test case has some database connection and while connecting to database it does not find the datasource which has been initialized in server.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but why are you connecting with a database while you're unittesting?

Comment: Could you add more information like the server used and may be share how you configure your datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are run outside of an IDE as often as they run inside.

It's usually accomplished using an integration build tool like Jenkins.   When code is checked into your version control system (Subversion or Git), the integration build tool pulls the code, runs all the tests, builds the package, and deploys it to a server.

I don't know how you configure the database connection URL.  If it has 'localhost' in it, you can be sure that it's incorrect.  You'll need to specify the host name using either a server name or IP address.  That IP address has to be visible from the server running the tests.  The database server has to allow connections from the test server.